# Style facebook 'like' button

Tags: css, facebook, coding-style

I'm struggling with this for a while now and without any success. Setting the style with jquery doesn't work, the same with  after the facebook iframe. Is there a way to perform this task ?

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=400&amp;action=like&amp;font=tahoma&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="false"></iframe>          

<style>
    .connect_widget_not_connected_text, .connect_widget_connected_text {
        color:white;
    }
    .connect_widget_connected_text a {
        color:#3B5998;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
        $('.connect_widget_not_connected_text').css('color', 'white');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure that you can figure out a CSS trick to style the button, but you are violating facebook Terms of Service by doing so. You are REQUIRED to display the like button in one of their official styles.

Comment: yea but then the text is invisible for site users so what's the problem of giving this little configurability.

Comment: Why is the text invisible? If you are looking for a dark like button you should use the colorscheme=dark configuration. You can see all the customization options here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like Anything beyond the customizations they allow is forbidden.

Comment: @Nathan Totten, I could not find anything regarding what is disallowed on the link above. Could you post a link with this information?

Comment: colorscheme="dark" makes a dark shaded button with gray text color. colorscheme="light" makes a like shaded button with black text. If you are displaying a Like button on a dark gray background, neither scheme works well.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, use a share link like

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=url_to_share&t=title_of_content
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can style an iframe content from a parent page in this fashion. You can try adding an id to the iframe and attempting to call it that way but even then I'm not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-your-facebook-fan-box/

Take a look a this page, maybe can guide you on this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an iframe implementation and there is probably no way you use use this implementation and style it as you want. However you might want to display other ways of implementating Facebook Like button like using XFBML