# Show text when user likes a FB page

Tags: facebook, heroku, facebook-like

We're trying to do some things on Facebook but to be honest we have no idea where to start.

We have a Facebook application which doesn't require any authorization. It's basically just a static page showing some of our information at the moment. We added it to a page as a tab.

We want to show some welcome text when a user likes our page. How should we go about this? I haven't used the Facebook SDK before so I'm completely lost.

Can we do this through the JS SDK? Check if a user has already liked our page and show a welcome message, otherwise show the like button? We're working with Heroku FB apps, not sure if that's important.

I'm not looking for complete example code, just some pointers would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style facebook 'like' button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833936/style-facebook-like-button)

Comment: You will be violating the Terms of Service by doing this.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll remove that part of the question as there's no real answer for it then.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9180071/facebook-user-id-on-iframe-page-tab-without-permissions/9197830#9197830) I gave earlier... You should be able to extract *some* data in this way - but the user **will** have to like the page...

Comment: Thanks. I'll certainly check it. All I'm trying to do right now figure out how we can know if a user likes our page or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a fan gate.

Here's a decent explanation:

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/customizing-facebook-iframe-application-signed_request_reveal_tab/

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];

if ($like_status) {
  echo "You like us";
}
else {
  echo "You don't like us yet";
}
```