# Facebook likebox changing link color

Tags: html, css, facebook

I wanted to change the title link color in the facebook likebox. I've tried doing this with regular css but to no avail as the content and styles are being loaded from external sources into an iframe it seems.

These are the selectors in question:

.fan_box .connect_action .name { line-height: 15px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }

a { cursor: pointer; color: #3B5998; }

So either I need to change the color in .name or a to yellow. I tried the following and it did not work:

.fan_box .connect_action .name { line-height: 15px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color:#F90 !important; }

a { cursor: pointer; color: #F90 !important; }

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style facebook 'like' button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833936/style-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot control the presentation of the contents of an iframe from the parent document. It's a completely different HTML document, so your CSS files will have no effect on it.